# How to know which instance deleted my file on a Linux server?

Tags: linux

I have a workflow pipeline which will generate data files on a Linux server periodically, and also a cleanup service which will remove data files which are older than a week.

However, sometimes I found that a new generated data file will be missing, which is definitely no older than a week. I'm not sure whether it is a logic bug of the cleanup service, or another program did it. Currently I don't have any idea on how to investigate this issue. Is there any method to log all the file deletion activities and related process id as well as process name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for `inotify` and friends.

Comment: Seems I need to write a program which uses inotify to monitor the file system changes, right? Is there an existing software?

Comment: I think there are some command utilities, but I am not very familiar with them: probably `gamin`, `incron`, `inotify-tools` (these are at least Debian packages names).